# I'm getting an error 'Null is not a subtype of type String in typecast (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

This is the Line in which I'm getting this error :    `_questions[_questionIndex]['questionText'] as String`

Comment: You should check what _questions[_questionIndex]['questionText'] is bringing beacause is coming null.

Comment: Please show more details about the code and the problem...

Comment: There's a syntax for removing null safety error and I'm not familiar with it

Answer (score 0):

You are using `as String` while it is receiving null. You can accept null value if the variable/widget accept null Or just provide a default value on null case like.

```dart
_questions[_questionIndex]['questionText'] ?? "got null"';
```

If the list item filed  has been defined as nullable, you can include `?`. More about [null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)